# Webpack code splitting and chunking

Tags: angularjs, webpack, code-splitting

I do not understand webpack, particularly code splitting and chunking. And I'm new to frontend dev.

Let's say I have a large multipage AngularJS app, where some pages (but not all) use pieces of a large Vendor library that consists of many AMD modules, all in separate files. So I have multiple entry points configured, one for each page. 
It seems reasonable to make the following bundles:

- A bundle for each page, containing my app's code, and maybe css etc
- A bundle containing my vendor's AMD modules (or at least, all the ones that are used by any of my pages)
- A bundle with common libs (e.g Angular, jquery, moment, etc) that are used by more than one of my app pages.

So I make the following webpage config:

```
//Webpack config.
var path = require('path');
var CommonsChunkPlugin = new require("webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin");
var glob = require('glob');
module.exports = {
    context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app'),
    entry: {
        page1Entry: './page1Entry.js',
        page2Entry: './page2Entry.js', //There are a few more of these
        vendor: glob.sync("../vendor/**/*.js")
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        chunkFilename: "[id].chunk.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        //Resolve non-relative path declared dependencies from the following directories.
        //This means look in the context root (/app) for my app code.
        //look in vendor folder for the vendor requires
        //everything else look in node_modules
        modulesDirectories: ['vendor', 'app', 'node_modules'],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({minChunks: 2, name: "commons"}),
        new CommonsChunkPlugin({name: "vendor", chunks: ['vendor']}),
    ]
}
```

This is not producing the desired outcome. What I get is something like this:

- page1Entry.bundle.js //contains my app code AND some Vendor libs
- page2Entry.bundle.js //contains just my app code
- vendor.bundle.js //pretty much completely empty
- commons.bundle.js //seems about right, has angular etc
  Some numbered chunks are created, e.g.:
- 4.chunk.js //small, contains some of my app logic that's used by TWO of my pages. NO vendor libs -- Why is this created?
- 6.chunk.js //huge, contains some of my app logic AND some vendor libs -- why?

Also, I see that the deployed code tries to get the numbered chunks from the server, but it's not getting them from my /deploymentcontext/js folder that all the chunks are deployed in - it's trying to load them from the page URL (e.g. http://my.domain/my/page/4.chunk.js). If I use the output.publicPath to configure this, I have to hardcode the deployment context. How can I fix this?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From (https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/971) I found part of the answer - need to include: __webpack_public_path__ = window.resourceBaseUrl; at the top of the entry point.